# How to set a custom icon of any client for the tasklist in awesomeWM v3.5.6?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

```
if (c.class == "Google-chrome") then
     c.icon = capi.image ( "/home/art-attack/.config/awesome/icons/chrome.png" )
end
```

I tried it but I always got an error i.e **attempt to call field 'image' (a nil value)**

```
{ rule = { class = "Google-chrome" },
  properties = { icon = beautiful.icon_chrome } },
```

Then I find another way to use properties **icon** in awful.rules and it worked but didn't change the icon instead it disabled the icon of that client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if c.class == "Google-chrome" then
    local icon = gears.surface("path/to/chrome.png")
    return text, bg, bg_image, icon
end
```

Add this code before

```
if capi.client.focus == c then
```

Comment: it's working fine.. but text gets invalid **<Invalid text>**

![IMAGE](http://oi60.tinypic.com/142gdbl.jpg)

Comment: seems like text can't initialize itself.. so i took this code before this line
`return text, bg, bg_image, not tasklist_disable_icon and c.icon or nil`
where text initialized first and it worked without any issue... thkx for ur reply

Answer (score 5):

To fix your first attempt, try this:

```
if c.class == "Google-chrome" then
    local icon = gears.surface("path/to/chrome.png")
    c.icon = icon._native
    icon:finish()
end
```

The line with `icon:finish()` is not necessary, but it exists to make sure you do not optimize this code. There is some dark garbage collection avoidance magic in there that you do not want to know, but the short story is: Never use `_native` unless you already have the surface itself saved in a variable.

Comment: still i got an error **attempt to index global 'gears' (a nil value)**

Comment: ohh.. sory i forgot to add **local gears = require("gears")** at the beginning
Thankx a lot it is working perfectly but an error is showing i.e **/usr/share/lua/5.1/lgi/record.lua:62: C stack overflow**